# How group by a sub select result that uses a TOP to reduce read rows (Sybase)

Tags: sap-ase

I'm trying to do a group by on a subselect result to reduce the amount of data processed.

`My_table` has more than 20 million rows.

example:

```
SELECT TOP 100 A.Column FROM (

SELECT TOP 500 Column FROM My_table) A

GROUP BY A.Column
```

I want the query to work with only 500 rows from my table, but when I use group by, it takes a lot of time, like if it was grouping up the whole 20 million rows when I'm only grouping 500.

Is there a way to make the sql motor only work with the 500 rows?

Answer (score 0):

If it's irrelevant to you which 500 rows are used, have you considered using `set rowcount`?

> set {rowcount number, textsize number} – causes the SAP ASE server to stop processing the query (select, insert, update, or delete) after the specified number of rows are affected. The number can be a numeric literal with no decimal point or a local variable of type integer.

[Infocenter source](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc34201_1500/html/dco_150/dco_150125.htm)

Comment: I just tried it. It seems it doesn't work over a group by clause.